# C# Inheritance constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, class, constructor

I have to many class properties and making another constructor just for one field is more harder then something like Inheritance.

For example i have class with one main costructor and one constructor with one parameter

```
public class mySampleClass
{
    //properties
    public string Default{get;set;}

    public mySampleClass()
    {
       // fill all properties with default values 
         Default = "First";  
    }

    public mySampleClass(string value)
    {
       // i want here to use default constructor and just manipulate  some property with 'value' 
        value = Default; // value = First
    }
}
```

Is it possible 2nd constructor to inherit all default properties from first constructor and just manipulate some data from additional value, or i must again build all default values for 2nd constructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "inherit all default properties" but you can make the second constructor *call* the first like this:

```
// Class name fixed to comply with conventions
public MySampleClass(string value) : this()
{
}
```

Normally, however, you do things the other way round: make constructors with *fewer* parameters call constructors with *more* parameters, leaving only the most specific constructor doing any work:

```
public MySampleClass() : this("default value")
{
   // Empty
}

public MySampleClass(string value)
{
   // Assign values to properties here
}
```

That generally avoids setting a default value in the parameterless constructor and then overwriting it in another one.

Comment: with : this() , everything from what i tested works fine. Thanks, this tip will save me a lot of time :)